# Error adding SSH node to Jenkins - Cannot read full block, EOF reached

Tags: java, jenkins, ssh

```
SSHLauncher{host='18.116.203.50', port=22, credentialsId='409435ce-c468-442b-8bd2-f00e79c4e8b4', jvmOptions='', javaPath='', prefixStartSlaveCmd='', suffixStartSlaveCmd='', launchTimeoutSeconds=60, maxNumRetries=10, retryWaitTime=15, sshHostKeyVerificationStrategy=hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.KnownHostsFileKeyVerificationStrategy, tcpNoDelay=true, trackCredentials=true}
[06/13/21 17:45:08] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 18.116.203.50:22.
Searching for 18.116.203.50 in /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts
Searching for 18.116.203.50:22 in /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts
[06/13/21 17:45:08] [SSH] SSH host key matches key in Known Hosts file. Connection will be allowed.
ERROR: Server rejected the 1 private key(s) for Jenk (credentialId:409435ce-c468-442b-8bd2-f00e79c4e8b4/method:publickey)
ERROR: Failed to authenticate as Jenk with credential=409435ce-c468-442b-8bd2-f00e79c4e8b4
java.io.IOException: Publickey authentication failed.
    at com.trilead.ssh2.auth.AuthenticationManager.authenticatePublicKey(AuthenticationManager.java:349)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.authenticateWithPublicKey(Connection.java:472)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.TrileadSSHPublicKeyAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(TrileadSSHPublicKeyAuthenticator.java:110)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.SSHAuthenticator.authenticate(SSHAuthenticator.java:431)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.SSHAuthenticator.authenticate(SSHAuthenticator.java:468)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.openConnection(SSHLauncher.java:886)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$1.call(SSHLauncher.java:434)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$1.call(SSHLauncher.java:421)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The connection is closed.
    at com.trilead.ssh2.auth.AuthenticationManager.deQueue(AuthenticationManager.java:72)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.auth.AuthenticationManager.getNextMessage(AuthenticationManager.java:100)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.auth.AuthenticationManager.authenticatePublicKey(AuthenticationManager.java:324)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot read full block, EOF reached.
    at com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.cipher.CipherInputStream.getBlock(CipherInputStream.java:81)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.cipher.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:108)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportConnection.receiveMessage(TransportConnection.java:232)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.receiveLoop(TransportManager.java:706)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager$1.run(TransportManager.java:502)
    ... 1 more
[06/13/21 17:45:08] [SSH] Authentication failed.
Authentication failed.
[06/13/21 17:45:08] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[06/13/21 17:45:08] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

Comment: getting errors on this connection. i need an assistance

Comment: Here is [some assistance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [some more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Were you able to find solution for this @nakel04

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem but Private Key didn't work for me then I create a new User with sudo privileges and assign it a password and configured credentials in Jenkins Global Credentials.

After that when Launch the agent by binding my newly created Credentials my problem got resolved.